# Trying to get the Initials to output on last window.. EX: First name = Joe, last name = Apple, university= Mercer OUTPUT = FLmercer

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation, charat

I'm trying to  output just the users first initials and college school name. Can this be done in just the html code or do I need to call a javascript function? I tried to do this inside the  tag just using charAt(0) or a substrate or the LEFT function. I can't figure this out and habe been working on it for hours. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
var firstname = prompt("Enter your first name: ", "");
var lastname = prompt("Enter your last name: ", "")
var univname = prompt("Enter your university name: ", "")

if (confirm("Your username is " + firstname + lastname + univname  ) {
    document.write("<h1>Thank you for signing up, " + firstname +
      "!</h1>");
  } 
  else {
    document.write("<h1>Have a great day!</h1>");
  }
```

Comment: Not clear on the question. How would you get "FL" from "Joe Apple"? Can you please rewrite the title and post to make it clearer?

Comment: firstname, lastname, univname i got it to work by charAt(0).var in the script!!